# Why can't I use bash freely after using the "At" utility? (Can't insert stdin until ctrl+c)

Tags: command-line, bash, at-command

I ran the following code block (an `at` timeout to uninstall PHPmyadmin). It should be scheduled to run 2 horus ahead, but I ran it in a timeout of 2 minutes, just to test it:

```
bash /dev/fd/50 50<< PMA_UNINSTALL | at 'now + 2 minutes'

apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y
PMA_UNINSTALL
```

The `at` utility seems to prevent me from using Bash freely, unless I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. `At` also prompts the following warning, which is normal, and hardcoded in the Utility's source code. When I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the warning vanish and I can use Bash regularly again.

> commands will be executed using /bin/sh

I don't say that it's the warning that prevents me from using Bash regularly as long it appears. I know the warning is just stdout and something else might prevent me from creating stdin.

What prevents me from creating stdin piping the above code block with `at` and how could I reach a state when I could execute commands piped with at, but use Bash freely right afterwards without interrupting `at` to work ?

Comment: I overlooked the start of your command - what are you trying to do there?

Comment: `at` takes a list of command on standard input (or from a file). In your code, `bash` _executes_ the command `apt-get`. You want something like `echo apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y | at 'now + 2 minutes'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me some time to see your real problem - you want to directly send a command to `at` instead of providing command(s) afterwards as i assumed.

There is no need for a complicated scheme, just type

```
echo 'apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y' | at 'now + 2 minutes'
```

When you do it this way `at` does not expect any input afterwards and you get back to the command line immediately.

---

<sub>(keeping my original answer here)</sub>

Issuing `at` gives you the possibility to list commands to execute. You have to tell `at` that you are done:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (This is also known as *End Of Transmisssion*)

Comment: When I click CTRL+D after executing code in my example above, nothing happens...

Answer (score 3):

*TL;DR: Those commands don't seem to do what you probably intend.*

If you're trying to make `at` execute `apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y` from `bash` in 2 minutes, then your code will not do what you want it to do.

The command on the left of the pipe (`|`) has your here document as its standard input. That command does not even run until the shell has read your complete here document.

From [3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/):

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line containing only *word* (with no trailing
>   blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used
>   as the standard input (or file descriptor *n* if *n* is specified) for
>   a command.

A command with a here document is, in effect, just a single command that must be fully read by the shell before it is executed. In your code, the shell reads input **until** `PMA_UNINSTALL` appears on a line by itself. Once that has happened, the shell **then** uses the content of the here document as file descriptor 50 for the command `bash /dev/fd/50`.

That command does not even start a new instance of `bash` until the here document has been fully read. When `bash` does run, it runs this command:

```
apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y
```

Since the whole left side of the pipe *including the here document* has its standard output piped to `at`, the input `at` gets is the *output* of `bash`, which is the output of `apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y`. `at` then attempts to interpret that output--not your `apt-get` command,  but its *output*--as a list of commands to execute in `/bin/sh`.

So this is almost certainly not what you mean to do.

I'm not sure why you don't get a shell prompt back right after entering that code. When I run it on a test machine, I get a shell prompt back in a couple of seconds. If you want to debug this, you can try running `apt-get purge phpmyadmin -y` interactively in bash. The way your code is written, that command runs completely *before* `at` returns to the shell (and before `at` can schedule anything). It would probably not be useful to debug this particular code further, though.

Comment: You should take a look at OP's question history on here and U&L to make sense of what they're trying to do. I personally think they're fixated on a particular solution and won't do anything else, but who knows?

Comment: Actually I didn't know there is something else called `tmux` at the time. I aim to use `tmux` but does need the following `tmux` solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335087/how-to-execute-code-in-a-new-tmux-session-from-within-current-session